# SQLite Inner Join

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

I am having some trouble with SQLite syntax.

I am able to get the following to work:

```
create table A as select * from DocumentFolders where DocumentFolders.folderId =202
create table B as select * from DocumentFolders where DocumentFolders.folderId =35 
create table C as select * from A join B on A.documentId = B.documentId
```

But I can't get this compound statement to work

```
select * from DocumentFolders where DocumentFolders.folderId =202 as A join select *
from DocumentFolders where DocumentFolders.folderId =35 as B on A.documentId =  
B.documentId
```

Was hoping to get some tips?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

When using joins, you still have a single SELECT statement, which can have only a single FROM/WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM DocumentFolders AS A
JOIN DocumentFolders AS B USING (documentId)
WHERE A.folderId = 202
  AND B.folderId = 35
```

Alternatively, you could move *complete* queries into subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM DocumentFolders WHERE folderId = 202)
JOIN (SELECT * FROM DocumentFolders WHERE folderId = 35)  USING (documentId)
```

In SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you could use common table expressions:

```
WITH
A AS (SELECT * FROM DocumentFolders WHERE folderId = 202),
B AS (SELECT * FROM DocumentFolders WHERE folderId = 35)
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B USING (documentId)
```